# Objects equal, hashcodes equal, HashSet contains one but not the other---how?

Tags: java, hashset

I have an (immutable) object, Group, which I am trying to use in a HashSet. However, I am getting odd results:

```
// Position is another immutable class, GroupType is an enum
Group t1 = new Group(new Position(0, 0), GroupType.ROW);
Group t2 = new Group(new Position(0, 0), GroupType.ROW);
Set<Group> s = new HashSet<Group>();
s.add(t1);
System.out.format("t1.hashCode(): %d\nt2.hashCode(): %d\nt1.hashCode() == t2.hashCode(): %b\nt1.equals(t2): %b\nt2.equals(t1): %b\ns.contains(t1): %b\ns.contains(t2): %b\n",
    t1.hashCode(),
    t2.hashCode(),
    t1.hashCode() == t2.hashCode(),
    t1.equals(t2),
    t2.equals(t1),
    s.contains(t1),
    s.contains(t2)
    );
```

results in the following:

```
t1.hashCode(): 486656595
t2.hashCode(): 486656595
t1.hashCode() == t2.hashCode(): true
t1.equals(t2): true
t2.equals(t1): true
s.contains(t1): true
s.contains(t2): false
```

t1 and t2 have identical hashcodes, and equals() claims that they are the same. How can the HashSet contain one and not the other?

(And no, none of those methods are secretly modifying t1 or t2; repeating the print statement garners the same results.)

Group.equals() is as follows:

```
public boolean equals(Group g2) {
    return (this.type.equals(g2.type)) && (this.basis.equals(g2.basis));
}
```

type is a (final) enum stored. basis is a Position, which has the following equals:

```
public boolean equals(Position pos) {
    return (x == pos.x) && (y == pos.y);
}
```

where x and y are internal, final variables.

However, I get the same results replacing it with:

```
public boolean equals(Group g2) {
    return true;
}
```

Comment: What does `t2.equals(t1)` print? Can you post the implementation of `equals`?

Comment: could you please provide `equals` code?

Comment: without seeing your hashcode or equals implementation, you are asking us to be psychic

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have a suspicion... my *guess* is that your equals method looks like this:

```
public boolean equals(Group other)
```

That's not overriding the built-in equals method, which is what `HashSet` will use. Make sure your equals method is:

```
@Override // Make the compiler check we're overriding something
public boolean equals(Object other)
```

Another way of testing this is:

```
Object o1 = t1;
Object o2 = t2;

System.out.println(o1.equals(o2));
System.out.println(o2.equals(o1));
```

Comment: That's why the @Overrides annotation is just great ;)

Comment: @Roflcoptr: Absolutely. It should have been part of the language from v1 :)

Comment: It's scary how often this guess is the correct answer based on the description of the symptoms alone

Comment: Yes, indeed, this is it. Thanks! I'll keep @Override in my notebook for the future.

Comment: @matt b There is a reason some mistakes are called typical.

Comment: @matt b Some problems are easily recognisable by their symptoms. If for example oyu wrote a program that rotated a cube on screen and the cube gradually started to flatten, I'd know what mistake you had made. :)

Answer (score -2):

it's a *set*. it will not add another element that is equal to an existing element. http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#add%28E%29

Comment: He's not trying to add another element.